# 3d from 2d images emgu

Tags: opencv, 3d, 2d, emgucv

In the center of my room I have a camera.I have images from this camera from different angles like this [sample](http://www.ex.ua/718372710658) where 1-camera,2,3,4-view from camera.
How to do 3d reconstruction from all this images?Need you help.I can not find good samle and turorial how to solve my trouble.I want to use emgu(opencv).But I am sure that it is correct.What can you advice?need all information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

honestly, structure from motion is a  difficult topic. don't expect fast or easy results

http://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/9781849517829_Chapter_04.pdf?utm_source=packtpub&utm_medium=free&utm_campaign=pdf

http://www.morethantechnical.com/2012/02/07/structure-from-motion-and-3d-reconstruction-on-the-easy-in-opencv-2-3-w-code/

https://github.com/libmv/libmv